# default app selection in settings app

Tags: system-settings

I changed my browser to a thoriem.deb package and deleted firefox. Now whenever I go to that section default apps it hangs for a long time, showing the wait or cancel dialog, before loading the page. Is there a way to fix the default apps file do settings app will stop hanging or should I just reinstall?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.